# read() and write() functions return -1 during a TCP connection on local connection (same computer) on C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, io

I wrote a code to transfer file contents from a client to a server. This means we update a certain file on the server side. This procedure continues every *N* seconds based on user input. However, I have faced an error which is:

**Even on local connection (same computer), the write() and read() functions return -1 during the file transfer. This issue might not even manifest itself from time to time. However, it is more likely to manifest when the user transfers larger files (more than 30MB). As a result, this issue is definitely there waiting for something to trigger it, which is a very inconvenient aspect for any program. What makes it odd is that if i use a sleep() function for example wait for 1 seconds and then write()/read() on socket, this problem does not occur. Please Explain why this happens and how can I remedy that.
Also, in every other code, all I ever see is exit(0) in case of read() or write() returns -1 during connection.
I appreciate all your guidance**

Unfortunately, I could not have found any solution for it in similar questions. I would be significantly grateful if you could explain why such problem occurs and how I can resolve it. I have explained the full procedure below for your convenience.

1. The main idea behind this code is to transfer data from a file which is regularly updated. As a result, we should send remaining data every *N* seconds to the server.
2. server (receiver) and client (sender) connect with each other (nothing new for pro users like you).
3. server (receiver) sends the amount of data persisted and user calculates how much data remained. After this step, both server and client know how much data should be transferred on the current iteration.
4. client reads all the remaining data to a *cacheBuffer* and closes the file. (I should say that the *cacheBuffer* is equal to the remaining bytes and work in both client and server)
5. Inside the main (inner) while loop, we copy from *cacheBuffer* to a *mssg struct* and later send the struct through the socket.
6. Similarly, the while loop inside the client reads the *struct mssg* and copy the data to its *cachebuffer*.
7. Finally when the sending/receiving is over, the receiver (server) writes the *cachebuffer* contents to the target file and the process will continue.

**client code**

```
/*
    How to compile ->
    (1) make all
        if no make was provided then gcc server.c utilityFunctionsMHZ.h -o server
    (2) ./server FILENAME PORT_NUMBER SLEEP_TIMER MAX_BUFFER_SIZE
        Example: ./server mainFile2.log 5500 10 4096
    (3) ./client FILENAME SERVER_ADDR PORT_NUMBER 
        Example: ./client mainFile.log 172.17.34.89 5500
*/  

#include "utilityFunctionsMHZ.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initial Error Check And Call Initializer
    if (argc < 4) 
    {   
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Please use the given format: ./client FILENAME SERVER_ADDR PORT_NUMBER\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (!isFileAvailable(argv[1], "client", NULL))
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        Initializer ("client", NULL);
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+%s] Make Sure to Run server First.\n", "client");
    }
        
    // Input Parameters  
    const char* fileLocFull = argv[1];
    char* serverIP          = argv[2];
    int portNumber          = atoi(argv[3]);

    // Buffer & Cache Properties and Size 
    struct bufferTCP* mssg = CreateBufferTCP();
    size_t MAX_CACHE_SIZE, CACHE_SIZE;
    char* cacheBuffer;

    // File Process, Data Structure (NACK-Sender & ACK-Reciever)
    FILE* filePtr_NACK;
    size_t fileMemory_NACK = 0;
    size_t fileMemory_ACK = 0;
    size_t fileRemainMemory = 0;

    // Create Socket via TCP Protocol & Error Check
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-client] Error in Socket Initiation!\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Socket Successfully Initiated.\n");
    // Socket main Structures
    struct sockaddr_in* serverAddr = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    
    // Socket Structures Memory Allocation Test
    if (serverAddr == NULL) 
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-client] Memory Allocation for sockadd_in strctures Failed!\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Memory Allocation for sockadd_in strctures Successfully Completed.\n");
    
    // Set-up server parameters
    bzero(serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));   //memset(serverAddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    serverAddr->sin_family      = AF_INET;
    //serverAddr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverIP);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, serverIP, &(serverAddr->sin_addr));
    serverAddr->sin_port        = htons(portNumber);

    // Connection Request to Server
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-client] Error in Connecting to Server!\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Connection Successfully Accepted.\n");

    if (read(sockfd, &MAX_CACHE_SIZE, sizeof(size_t)) == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-client] Error in MAX CACHE Size Negitiation!\n"); 
    else 
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] CACHE Size is Set Equal to Server: %lu.\n", MAX_CACHE_SIZE);
    
    // Initializing Sender Sleep Clock
    size_t sleepTimer;
    if (read(sockfd, &sleepTimer, sizeof(size_t)) == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-client] Error in Sleep Timer Negitiation!\n", 1, 1); 
    else 
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Sleep Timer is Set Equal to Server: %lu\n", sleepTimer); 
    
    int iack;
    int ACKFLAG = 0;
    size_t OveralIteration = 0;
    size_t SentBytes;
    size_t Not_Written = 0;
    ssize_t readFLAG;
    ssize_t writeFLAG;
    size_t InnerIteration = 0;

    fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "**********************Client-Side::Sending Started**************************\n"); 
    while (1)
    {
        fileMemory_NACK = FileSizeCalculator(fileLocFull);

        // File Status @ Server (Reciever) 
        if (read(sockfd, &fileMemory_ACK, sizeof(size_t)) == -1)
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-client] Error in reading File Info!\n"); 
        else
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] File (Size) Info is Recieved Successfully.\n"); 

        // Send-Recieve Validity
        fileRemainMemory = fileMemory_NACK - fileMemory_ACK;
            
        // Send Expecting Data Size For Server
        if (write(sockfd, &fileRemainMemory, sizeof(size_t)) == -1)
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-client] Failed To Send Remaining Memory Info!\n"); 
        else
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Session [%lu] Overview: \nACK Memory is %lu\nNACK Memory is %lu\nRemaining Memory is: %lu\n\n", 
                                        OveralIteration, fileMemory_ACK, fileMemory_NACK, fileRemainMemory); 
        // Assess Sending
        if (fileMemory_NACK == fileMemory_ACK) 
        {
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Remaining Memory is Zero. Send Process Will Contine After %lu[s] Timeout.\n", sleepTimer);;  
            continue;
        }
        else if (fileRemainMemory < BUFFER_MAX)
        {
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Remaining Buffer is Smaller Than Cache Limit %lu. Send Process Will Contine After %lu[s] Timeout.\n",
                              BUFFER_MAX, sleepTimer);  
            Not_Written++;
            if (Not_Written < 10) 
                continue;
            else
                Not_Written = 0;
        }
        
        // Creating Cache
        CACHE_SIZE = fileRemainMemory;
        cacheBuffer = (char*) calloc (CACHE_SIZE, sizeof(char));
        bzero(cacheBuffer, CACHE_SIZE);
        
        // Copy Data From File to CACHE-Buffer
        filePtr_NACK = fopen(fileLocFull, "r");
        fseek(filePtr_NACK, fileMemory_ACK, SEEK_SET);
        fread(cacheBuffer, sizeof(char), CACHE_SIZE, filePtr_NACK);
        fclose(filePtr_NACK);
        
        ACKFLAG = 0;
        SentBytes = 0;
        fileRemainMemory = CACHE_SIZE;
        InnerIteration = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            // EXIT CONDITION
            if (fileRemainMemory == 0) break;
            
            // Evaluate Buffer Size
            if (fileRemainMemory >= BUFFER_MAX)                     
                mssg->BUFFER_USED = BUFFER_MAX;
            else 
                mssg->BUFFER_USED = fileRemainMemory;
                
            // Copy From CACHE to Socket Buffer and Send
            memcpy(mssg->mssgPtr, cacheBuffer+SentBytes, mssg->BUFFER_USED);
            writeFLAG = write(sockfd, mssg, sizeof(struct bufferTCP)); 
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Iter %ld :: %ld/%ld Sent!\n", InnerIteration++, writeFLAG, sizeof(struct bufferTCP)); 
            // Cases:
            if (writeFLAG == -1)
            {
                // Display Problem
                fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[-client] Error While Sending Buffer!\n");
                fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[-client] %s\n", strerror(errno));
            } 
            else if (writeFLAG < sizeof(struct bufferTCP))
            {
                // Display Problem
                fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[-client] Only %ld/%ld Sent!\n", writeFLAG, sizeof(struct bufferTCP)); 
            }   
            else
            {
                // In Session Statistics    
                fileRemainMemory -= mssg->BUFFER_USED;
                SentBytes        += mssg->BUFFER_USED;
                fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] (%lu) Current-Iteration | (%lu) Total-Sent | (%lu) Remaining.\n", writeFLAG, SentBytes, fileRemainMemory);
            }   
            bzero(mssg->mssgPtr, BUFFER_MAX); 
        }
        if (writeFLAG != -1 && fileRemainMemory == 0)
        {
            fileMemory_ACK = SentBytes;
            OveralIteration++;
        }
            
        // Session Summary
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+client] Session %lu Summary:\nACK Memory is %lu :: Remaining Memory is: %lu\n\n", 
                                          OveralIteration, fileMemory_ACK, fileRemainMemory);   
        free(cacheBuffer);
        // Exit Condition
        if (isEnd (sleepTimer, "client"))  break;

    }
    fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "\n***********************Client-Side::Sending Ended***************************\n"); 

    close(sockfd);
    free(serverAddr);
    free(mssg);

    return 0;
}
```

**server code:**

```
/*
    How to compile ->
    (1) make all
        if no make was provided then gcc server.c utilityFunctionsMHZ.h -o server
    (2) ./server FILENAME PORT_NUMBER SLEEP_TIMER CHACHE_SIZE_MAX
        Example: ./server mainFile2.log 5500 10 4096
    (3) ./client FILENAME SERVER_ADDR PORT_NUMBER
        Example: ./client mainFile.log 172.17.34.89 5500
*/  

#include "utilityFunctionsMHZ.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initial Error Check And Call Initializer
    if (argc < 5) 
    {
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Please use the following format to initiate the ./server FILENAME PORT_NUMBER SLEEP_TIMER MAX_CACHE_SIZER\n");
        exit(0);
    }   
    else
    {
        Initializer ("server", NULL);
    }
        
    // Input Parameters  
    const char* fileLocFull = argv[1];
    int portNumber          = atoi(argv[2]);         
    size_t sleepTimer       = atoi(argv[3]); 
    size_t MAX_CACHE_SIZE   = atoi(argv[4]);
    size_t WaitQueue        = 5;
    
    // server :: Socket Accept Client Request
    socklen_t socklen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    // File Process, Data Structure (NACK is the Sender/Client Side)
    if (!isFileAvailable(argv[1], "server", NULL))
    {
        FILE* filePtr_ACK = fopen(fileLocFull, "w");
        fclose(filePtr_ACK);
    }
    
    //size_t checker = FileCorrector (fileLocFull);
    size_t checker = FileModifier (fileLocFull);

    // File Process, Data Structure (NACK-Sender & ACK-Reciever)
    FILE* filePtr_ACK;
    size_t fileMemory_ACK = 0;
    size_t fileRemainMemory = 0;
    
    // Buffer Properties and Size (Set Sender/Client Buffer-Size Equal to Server)
    struct bufferTCP* mssg = CreateBufferTCP();
    // Cache properties
    size_t CACHE_SIZE;
    char* cacheBuffer;

    // socket End-Point
    int sockfd, sockfd_new;
    // client :: Initiation Socket via TCP Protocol & Error Check
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Error in Socket Initiation!\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Socket Successfully Initiated.\n");

    // Socket main Structures
    struct sockaddr_in* serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in* clientAddr;
    serverAddr =  malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));       
    clientAddr =  malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    
    // Socket Structures Memory Allocation Test
    if (clientAddr == NULL || serverAddr == NULL)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Memory Allocation for sockadd_in strctures Failed!\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Memory Allocation Successfully Completed.\n");
    
    bzero(serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); //memset(serverAddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    bzero(clientAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); //memset(clientAddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    
    // set-up Server parameters
    serverAddr->sin_family      = AF_INET;
    serverAddr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;   // inet_addr(clientIP);
    serverAddr->sin_port        = htons(portNumber);

    // server :: Socket Binding
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Error in Socket Binding!\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Socket Successfully Binded.\n");
    
    // server :: Socket Listening
    if (listen(sockfd, WaitQueue) == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Error while Listening!\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Listening...\n");
    
    // server :: Socket Listening
    sockfd_new = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) clientAddr, &socklen);
    if (sockfd_new == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Error in Accepting Client Connection!\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Connection Successfully Accepted.\n");

    // Establishing BUFFER_MAX_SIZE (Set Sender/Client Buffer-Size Equal to Server)
    if (write(sockfd_new, &MAX_CACHE_SIZE, sizeof(size_t)) == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Error in Buffer Size Negitiation!\n");
    else 
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] MAX Buffer-Size is Sent to client: %lu.\n", MAX_CACHE_SIZE);
    
    // Initializing Sender Sleep Clock (Set Sender/Client Buffer-Size Equal to Server)
    if (write(sockfd_new, &sleepTimer, sizeof(size_t)) == -1)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Error in Sleep Timer Negitiation!\n");
    else 
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Sleep-Timer is Sent to client: %lu\n", sleepTimer);

    int ACKFLAG = 0, CONFLAG = 0;
    size_t OveralIteration = 0;
    size_t SentBytes;
    size_t Not_Written;
    int iack = 0;
    ssize_t readFLAG;
    ssize_t writeFLAG;
    size_t InnerIteration = 0;

    fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "**********************Server-Side::Recieving Started**************************\n");
    while (1)
    {
        // File Status @ Server (Reciever) 
        fileMemory_ACK = FileSizeCalculator(fileLocFull);
        
        // Send ACK Status
        if (write(sockfd_new, &fileMemory_ACK, sizeof(size_t)) == -1)
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Error in Sending File Info!\n");
        else
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] File (Size) Info Sent Successfully.\n"); 

        // Recieve Expecting Data Size From Client
        if (read(sockfd_new, &fileRemainMemory, sizeof(size_t)) == -1)
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Failed to Recieve Remaining Memory Info!\n"); 
        else
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Session [%lu] Overview:\nACK Memory is: %lu\nRemaining Memory is: %lu\n\n", 
                                    OveralIteration, fileMemory_ACK, fileRemainMemory); 
        if (fileRemainMemory == 0) 
        {
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Remaining Memory is Zero. Process Will Contine After %lu[s] Timeout.\n", sleepTimer); 
            continue;
        }
        else if (fileRemainMemory < BUFFER_MAX)
        {
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Remaining Buffer is Smaller Than Cache Limit %lu. Recieve Process Will Contine After %lu[s] Timeout.\n",
                              BUFFER_MAX, sleepTimer);  
            Not_Written++;
            if (Not_Written < 10) 
                continue;
            else
                Not_Written = 0;
        }

        // Creating Cache
        CACHE_SIZE = fileRemainMemory;
        cacheBuffer = calloc (CACHE_SIZE, sizeof(char));
        bzero(cacheBuffer, CACHE_SIZE);

        ACKFLAG = 0;
        SentBytes = 0;
        fileRemainMemory = CACHE_SIZE;
        InnerIteration = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            // EXIT CONDITION
            if (fileRemainMemory == 0) break;

            // Recieve Buffer
            readFLAG = read(sockfd_new, mssg, sizeof(struct bufferTCP));    
            fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Iter %ld :: %ld/%ld Sent!\n", InnerIteration++, readFLAG, sizeof(struct bufferTCP)); 
            // Cases:
            if (readFLAG == -1) 
            {
                // Display Problem
                fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[-server] Error While Reading Buffer Size!\n"); 
            }
            else if (readFLAG < sizeof(struct bufferTCP))
            {
                // Copy From CACHE to Socket Buffer
                fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[-server] Only %ld/%ld Recieved!\n",readFLAG, sizeof(struct bufferTCP)); 
                fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[-server] %s\n", strerror(errno));
            }
            else
            {
                // Copy From CACHE to Socket Buffer
                memcpy(cacheBuffer+SentBytes, mssg->mssgPtr, mssg->BUFFER_USED);
                // In Session Statistics    
                fileRemainMemory -= mssg->BUFFER_USED;
                SentBytes        += mssg->BUFFER_USED;
                fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] (%lu) Current-Iteration | (%lu) Total-Sent | (%lu) Remaining.\n", readFLAG, SentBytes, fileRemainMemory);
            }   
            bzero(mssg->mssgPtr, BUFFER_MAX); 
        }       
        if (readFLAG != -1 && fileRemainMemory == 0)
        {
            fileMemory_ACK = SentBytes;
            // Copy Data From File to CACHE-Buffer
            filePtr_ACK = fopen(fileLocFull, "a");
            fwrite(cacheBuffer, sizeof(char), CACHE_SIZE, filePtr_ACK);
            fclose(filePtr_ACK);
            OveralIteration++;
        }
        
        // Session Summary-alIteration, fileMemory_ACK, fileRemainMemory);  
        free(cacheBuffer);
        // Exit Condition
        if (isEnd (sleepTimer, "server"))  break;
    }
    fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "\n***********************Server-Side::Recieving Ended***************************\n");
    
    close(sockfd);
    close(sockfd_new);
    free(serverAddr);
    free(clientAddr);
    free(mssg);

    return 0;
}
```

**Library used**

```
#ifndef utilityFunctionsMHZ_H
#define utilityFunctionsMHZ_H

#include <stdio.h>      //:: standard IO c-functions
#include <string.h>     //:: standard c-string functions
#include <unistd.h>     //:: standard POSIX operating system API (read/write/send/recv)
#include <stdlib.h>     //:: standard ALLOC c-functions (malloc, atoi)
#include <sys/types.h>  //:: definitions of data types used in sys/socket & netinet/in
#include <sys/socket.h> //:: definitions of structures needed for internet domain such as (struct sockaddr)
#include <netinet/in.h> //:: definitions of (struct sockaddr_in)
#include <netdb.h>      //:: definitions of (struct hostnet) to store info of a given host & IPV-4
#include <arpa/inet.h>  //:: inet()
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdarg.h>     //:: Variable Input function
#include <errno.h>
#define BUFFER_MAX 1024

struct bufferTCP
{
    char mssgPtr[BUFFER_MAX];
    size_t BUFFER_USED;
};

// Usefull functions
struct bufferTCP* CreateBufferTCP();
void WriteLog(const char* logFileName, const char* mssg);
size_t FileCorrector (const char* fileName);;
FILE* FileOpenSafe (const char* fileName, const char* rwaMode);
size_t FileSizeCalculator (const char* fileName);
void fprintfSwitchable(FILE* stream, int errFlag, const char* mssg, ...);
FILE* FileOpenSafe (const char* fileName, const char* rwaMode);
size_t FileSizeCalculator (const char* fileName);
size_t FileCorrector (const char* fileName);
size_t FileModifier(const char* fileName);
void Initializer (const char* caller, FILE* stream);
int isEnd (size_t sleepTimer, const char* caller);
int isFileAvailable (const char* fileLocFull, const char* caller, FILE* stream);

void WriteLog(const char* logFileName, const char* mssg)
{
    FILE* logFilePtr = fopen(logFileName, "a");
    //fputs(mssg, logFilePtr);
    fclose(logFilePtr);
}


void fprintfSwitchable(FILE* stream, int errFlag, const char* mssg, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, mssg);

    if (stream == NULL)
    {
        vfprintf(stdout, mssg, args);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else
    {
        vfprintf(stream, mssg, args);
        fflush(stream);
    }    

    if (errFlag)  exit(1);
        
    va_end(args);
}


FILE* FileOpenSafe (const char* fileName, const char* rwaMode)
{
    if (fileName == NULL)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, -1, "FileName or Location is Incorrect!\n");

    FILE* filePtr = fopen(fileName, rwaMode);

    if (filePtr == NULL)
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, -1, "File Location is Invalid Or File Does Not Exists!\n");

    return filePtr;
}


size_t FileSizeCalculator (const char* fileName)
{
    FILE* filePtr = FileOpenSafe(fileName, "r");
    int fileDescriptor = fileno(filePtr);
    struct stat fileInfo;
    bzero(&fileInfo, sizeof(struct stat));
    fstat(fileDescriptor, &fileInfo);
    size_t fileSize =  fileInfo.st_size;
    fclose(filePtr);

    return fileSize;
}

size_t FileCorrector (const char* fileName)
{
    size_t fileSize = FileSizeCalculator (fileName);
    size_t fileSizeTrue;
    if (fileSize == 0)
    {
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "File is Empty, thus requires no correction!\n");
        return 0;
    }
        
    // Main & Temp File
    FILE* mainFile = FileOpenSafe (fileName, "r");
    FILE* tempFile = FileOpenSafe("temp", "w");
    
    // Fault Detection (\00 0\0 00) and correct
    char checkBuff[3];
    char curserrChar;
    
    size_t ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < fileSize; ii++)
    {
        curserrChar = fgetc(mainFile);
        //printf("%c", curserrChar);
        if (curserrChar == '\00')
        {    
            fileSizeTrue = ftell(mainFile)-2;
            break;
        }
        fputc(curserrChar, tempFile);
    }
    fclose(mainFile);
    fclose(tempFile);

    // Remove The Old File
    if (remove(fileName) == 0) 
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "Faulty File (%s) Removed Successfully.\n", fileName);
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "Error while Removing the Faulty File: %s!\n", fileName);


    // Remove The Old File
    if (rename("temp", fileName) == 0) 
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "Corrected File Renamed Successfully.\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "Error while Removing the Faulty File: %s!\n");

    fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "Correction Implemented Successfully.\n");

    return fileSizeTrue;
}


size_t FileModifier(const char* fileName)
{
    size_t fileSize = FileSizeCalculator (fileName);
    size_t fileSizeTrue;
    if (fileSize == 0)
    {
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] File is Empty, thus requires no correction.\n");
        return 0;
    }
        
    // Main & Temp File
    FILE* mainFile = FileOpenSafe (fileName, "r");
    FILE* tempFile = FileOpenSafe("temp", "w");
    
    // Fault Detection (\00 0\0 00) and correct
    char checkBuff[3];
    char curserrChar;
    size_t ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < fileSize; ii++)
    {
        curserrChar = fgetc(mainFile);
        if (curserrChar == '\00') break;
        fputc(curserrChar, tempFile);
    }
    fclose(mainFile);
    fclose(tempFile);


    mainFile = FileOpenSafe (fileName, "w");
    tempFile = FileOpenSafe("temp", "r");
    fileSizeTrue = FileSizeCalculator ("temp");

    ii=0;
    for (ii = 0; ii < fileSizeTrue; ii++)
    {
        curserrChar = fgetc(tempFile);
        fputc(curserrChar, mainFile);
    }
    
    fclose(mainFile);
    fclose(tempFile);

    // Remove The Old File
    if (remove("temp") == 0) 
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] Temp File Removed Successfully.\n");
    else
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 1, "[-server] Error while Removing the Faulty File!\n");

    fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+server] File Modifier Executed Successfully.\n");

    return fileSizeTrue;
}


void Initializer (const char* caller, FILE* stream)
{
    // Initial confirmation client side
    char checkSend;
    fprintfSwitchable(stream, 0, "[+%s] Start Process [Y/N]: ", caller);
    scanf(" %c", &checkSend);
    if (checkSend == 'N' || checkSend == 'n')
    {
        fprintfSwitchable(stream, 0, "[-%s] Abort Process As Requested!\n", caller);
        exit(0);
    } 
    else
        return;
}
    
int isEnd (size_t sleepTimer, const char* caller)
{
    // Exit Material
    fd_set          s;
    struct timeval  timeout;
    char exitFlag[12];
    memset(&exitFlag, 'F', 12);
    int sFlag;

    fflush(stdout);
    FD_ZERO(&s);
    FD_SET(0, &s);
    timeout.tv_sec = sleepTimer; timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    sFlag = select(1, &s, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    
    if      (sFlag < 0) 
        return 0;
    else if (sFlag == 0) 
    {
        fflush(stdout);
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "-\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fgets(exitFlag, 12, stdin);
        fprintfSwitchable(NULL, 0, "[+%s] To Quit, please enter \"exit\": ", caller); 
        fflush(stdout);
        if ( memcmp(&exitFlag, "exit", 4) == 0 ) 
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}

int isFileAvailable (const char* fileLocFull, const char* caller, FILE* stream)
{
    // Checks if The Target Send File Exists!
    FILE* filePtr_NACK = fopen(fileLocFull, "r");
    if (filePtr_NACK == NULL)
    {
        fprintfSwitchable(stream, 0, "[-%s] Not Such File Name Exists!\n", caller);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintfSwitchable(stream, 0, "[+%s] File Found Successfully.\n", caller);
        fclose(filePtr_NACK);
        return 1;
    }
    
}


void copyWithOffsetDest(char* dest, const char* src, size_t start, size_t length)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        dest[start+i] = src[i];
}

void copyWithOffsetSource(char* dest, const char* src, size_t start, size_t length)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        dest[i] = src[i+start];
}


struct bufferTCP* CreateBufferTCP()
{
    struct bufferTCP* mssg = (struct bufferTCP*) 
                malloc(sizeof(struct bufferTCP));
    return mssg;
}

#endif
```

**Makefile**

```
all:    client server

ftpclient: client.c
    gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall $< -o $@

ftpserver: server.c
    gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f client server *.o *~ core
    rm server client
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Nobody will bother reading hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Borked anyway because of failure to correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like read(), write() when applied to a TCP byte stream.   Not sure what all that 'sleepTimer' 'N seconds'stuff is - sounds iffy to me, is that just for testing?

Comment: @aulven Thanks for your respond. I will produce a smaller example. I appreciate our suggestion. Meanwhile, can you please answer me a small question which is why read and write would return -1 on a local connection during tcp connection? More importantly how can I remedy such situations and maybe re-establish the connection (not just exit)? thanks in advance

Comment: I mean..if it was me, I would assemble a fixed-size header struct first, with filespec, filesize etc and write it in a loop, accumulating the actua bytes sent, (as detrmined by the result returned by write), until I was sure all the header had gone.  Similar at peer - read in a loop until I have received ALL the header.  Then, the file xfer can begin, write, read until file has gone over, then close socket at client, so getting 0 from the server read return and so signaling it to close the file.  Your design seems a bit over-complex'

Comment: ...as for the -1 return, you should get the extended error information from your OS, (errno, whatever).

Comment: You are assuming throughout that `read()` fills the buffer to the length provided. TCP provides no such guarantee. You have to store the result of `read()`, and loop until you get what you expect. It is impossible to write correct TCP networking code without storing the result of `read()` into a variable and testing it for both -1 and zero, and otherwise using it as the number of bytes actually read.

Comment: @user207421 Your suggestion is very interesting. I'll check it and post the results. Thank you very much by the way.

Comment: Dear @MartinJames thanks for your response. I exactly did as you have written above, and I will send some of the results for you in below. The error I receive is "connection reset by peer" which is odd because both ends are on my local host. How this happens in local host? More importantly how can I remedy it. Its should not always be an exit(0) when facing similar problems in more realistic applications. It would be awesome if you could point me to the right direction to understand why such issue occurs, and how to get rid of it. Thanks in advance

Comment: "connection reset by peer" means that the program on the other side of the TCP connection has closed its side of the connection.  This could happen if the other program called `close()` or `shutdown()` on the socket, or if the program crashed or exited for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question.
As @user207421 and @Martin James suggested **(Thank You Both)**, the problem was regarding the write() read() IO. I don't yet understand how it led to segmentation but the **lesson** was that read() and write() functions require loop to send and receive data as we expected. Otherwise, they do something else and we cannot simply predict it. In below, I appended how I fixed the code. I hope it will save other people from making same mistakes.

**Server Loop**

```
readFLAG = 0;
bzero(mssg->mssgPtr, BUFFER_MAX);
while ( (readFLAG = read(sockfd_new, (mssg->mssgPtr)+readFLAG, BUFFER_MAX-readFLAG)) != BUFFER_MAX )
{
    if (readFLAG == 0 ||  mssg->mssgPtr[readFLAG] == '\0')
        break;
}

mssg->BUFFER_USED = readFLAG;
```

**Client Loop**

```
bzero(mssg->mssgPtr, BUFFER_MAX);
memcpy(mssg->mssgPtr, cacheBuffer+SentBytes, mssg->BUFFER_USED);
            
while ( (writeFLAG = write(sockfd, mssg->mssgPtr, mssg->BUFFER_USED)) != mssg->BUFFER_USED );
```

Comment: What `read()` does is provide you with as many incoming bytes as it currently has available in memory to give you (or if it doesn't currently have any bytes to give you, it will block until it does have something).  What `write()` does is accept from you as many bytes as it currently has buffer-space to hold, or if it can't accept all bytes, it will block until enough buffer-space has become available to accept them.  It's important to note that for TCP, the behavior of both functions is unrelated to the amount of data the remote program previously sent/received in any given call.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner Your notes are valuable.